# Get specific field from raw JSON to PATCH

Tags: json, rest, go

I'm trying to build a PATCH method for my REST API. What I can't understand is how can I take the name from a JSON raw field to use it as a parameter in the UPDATE query so the query can know which field to update because, unlike PUT, PATCH needs to update only one field and not the whole row in the DB. I'm using SQLite3

EDIT:
Code:

```
func PatchServer(c echo.Context) error {
    patchedServer := new(structs.Server)
    requestID := c.Param("id")
    if err := c.Bind(patchedServer); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if reflect.TypeOf(patchedServer.Name).Kind() != reflect.String || reflect.TypeOf(patchedServer.Components).Kind() != reflect.Int {
        panic("Insert a string or an int")
    } else {
        sql := "UPDATE servers SET server_name = CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? END WHERE id = ?"
        stmt, err := db.Get().Prepare(sql)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err2 := stmt.Exec(patchedServer.Name, patchedServer.Name, requestID)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(patchedServer.ID, patchedServer.Name, patchedServer.Components)
    fmt.Println("Requested id: ", requestID)
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Patched!")
    }
```

Comment: This question seems a bit too general to me; it would help if you could add some specific details about what you're trying to do, and what hasn't worked so far (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a useful guide)

Comment: A code example of what you tried and did not work might clarify things.

Comment: @RickyA Edited with current code. I started go a week back so it might not be the best code. My problem is how can my update query know in which column the patch aka single update should happen. Now i use CASE because i have 2 columns what. Problem is what if i have 1000.